# Embed an dotm file into an Excel document

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have a dotm file( macro enabled word template). I want to insert it into an Excel file and I want to open it by the clicking of a command button in Excel form. The problem is, when I open this dotm file, it comes as docx file not dotm file. It is possible if I use the `link to file option` but I don't want to use that option. Is there any other option to embed dotm file in excel?

Thanks in advance!